# Control from Driver class to another and back

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on Selenium Webdriver and have general Java question. My test package in Java has multiple independent classes (Test 1,2,3 ..etc). I have a driver class (outside of that package) that should invoke and run Test 1, then get the result to a variable in driver class, then to Class 2 & back to driver and then to other classes. On driver class after executing each test class, I want to record whether it's successful or not. Please suggest different ways it cab be done. I thought about constructors, but that wouldnt return anything back from classes. I can call methods of individual classes, but that makes my driverclass look ugly when I develop rest of the classes that could be close to 50+. One more point to add here is that the selection of which class (Test 1 / 2/ 3) to be run would depend on an input from user (For now, I just have Temp1, Temp2 strings, down the line I will replace them with an input from user (spreadsheet or something) that tells which class file to be run.

Here is my driver class:

```
public class Driver {

 public static String Temp1 = "Test1";
 public static String Temp2 = "Test2";

 @BeforeSuite
 public void initialize() {
    System.out.println("Before Suite ");
 }

 @Test
 public void CallerSripts() {
    System.out.println("Calling");
    new Test1();
    }

}



package Tests;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import Base.Driver;

public class Test1{

 @BeforeClass
 public void print() {
    System.out.println("Befire test 1 ");
 }

 @Test
 public Test1() {
    System.out.println("Inside called 1");
 }
}

package Tests;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import Base.Driver;

public class Test2{

 @BeforeClass
 public void print() {
    System.out.println("Before Test2 ");
 }

 @Test
 public void Here() {
    System.out.println("Inside called 2");
 }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "invoke"? Call a method? Load the class?

Comment: Perhaps you could use jUnit? Also have a look at the jUnit TestSuite class that combines multiple jUnit Test classes.

Comment: I want to load the class, execute..

Comment: This is StackOverflow not a university lecture class. Here ,you will have to provide what have you tried.So what have you tried?

Comment: I added the sample code here. Please help now

Comment: I don't understand why you are instantiating `Test1` in class `Driver`, since the first is inheriting from the latter? And you are creating an instance and don't use it? What are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: I wouldn't need to extend Driver in Test 1 /2, i will remove that. However, my objective is to hold the control primarily in Driver class and execute the respective test class based on the user input. Please refer to my original post for detailed info.

Comment: I think the only alternative to invoking 50+ methods in your `Driver` class is using reflection then. Or perhaps you find a solution based on [JUnit](http://junit.org) as @Brainstorm pointed out. But you did not comment on that...